# Decimal validation in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to make an example `MvcMusicStore` application from MSDN. My code of Model class is:

```
    public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
        [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Price must be positive")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Album Art URL")]
        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }


        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
```

And I generated the code for Controller by Scaffolding (CRUD template). But I have got problem with validation of Price in my View. This is the fragment of my Razor code in view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
```

Everything looks good, client-side validation works as expected, but problem lies by the server-side validation. This is the method code in Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Albums.Add(album);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "Id", "Name", album.GenreId);
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "Id", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        return View(album);
    }
```

In the beginning of this method I inserted a break point. Debugger says that `album.Price` always equals 0. I suppose it is translation from text in textbox to decimal problem in Controller's method. I always inserted values point separated such as 10.99, 12.65, 19.99, etc. It only works with integer values like 3, 10, 14, etc.

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked if this is not caused by the culture of your system? if you have culture set to use ',' instead of '.' to separate decimals it would cause this issue.

Comment: As I mentioned, client-side validation works as expected, so I doubt it very much. But I will check it.

Comment: I checked it. I had comma separated decimal notation indeed, but after changing separator to point, there hasn't changed anything in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could explicitly set the culture to some culture in which the decimal separator is `.`:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Comment: Where should I insert it?

Comment: That would be in web.config. See this how-to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.ASPX